# How can i upload image from computer/url in mongodb?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using

```
"express": "~4.9.0",
"mongodb": "~2.0"
```

Html looks like this

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And js looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.forms['name']).on('submit', function() { 

        $.ajax({
            url: "/upload",
            method: "POST",
            //.... ???? .....
        });
    });
});
```

Server part is something like this

```
// /upload
exports.post = function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var img = ??? //dont know how to do this part

    user.authorize(username, password, img)
}
```

authorize is schema method and it looks like this

```
var user = new User({name: username, password: password});
user.img.data = // ???
user.companyLogo.contentType = 'jpg';
user.save();
```

How can i upload files this way in mongodb?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the relevant parts of your server-side code to your question.

Comment: @tsnorri i have added part of mongoose.schema and /upload

Comment: Do you use some framework or WSGI directly?